# uncaught exception: Syntax error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, prestashop

Please check

http://arabiannights.thestagingurl.com/egyptian-hookhas/157-ho-101.html

There is this error `"uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@href^='#']"` due to which the the navigation on the left is not appearing on any of the products page however its appearing fine on all other pages. :(

Comment: Is it just me to read "the-stag-in-"?  Dirty mind, a joy forever :)  Hookahs btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jQuery 1.3+ (1.4.2 is used on that site), the `@` is removed for [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), it should just be `[href^='#']` now.

Comment: Hi nick,why does it work on homepage then? And I don't seem to find [href^='#'] anywhere in my code (yes I wrote the code in `<head>`)

Comment: @atif089 - It has to be in a plugin somewhere, looking

Comment: @atif089 - I'm still looking for where it's used, but the reason it works on the homepage is you're including jQuery 1.4.2 **and** 1.2.3 later, in which the `@` does work...you should only include jQuery once.

Comment: @atif089 - It's in `jquery.idTabs.modified.js`, `$("a[@href^='#']", this).click(function() {`, you'd need to update that plugin.